# Can anyone help me identify this timestamp format?

Tags: sql-server, unix, oracle10g

I am importing information from an Oracle database on an AIX machine into SQL Server 2008r2.  I inherited this process from the previous DBA.  The timestamp comes in the following format: 4170180534, which, based on the conversion function in the executable, converts to the following:

```
417 = year (2017)
018 = days since beginning of year (018 converts to Jan 18)
0534 = time HH:mm
```

I need to provide maintenance on the conversion function (the previous DBA retired in 2016, so the date conversion function only works through the end of 2016).

Can anyone tell me exactly what this timestamp format is?  I assume the '4' stands for the century, but it would be nice to know for sure what the first digit of the value actually is.

Comment: Do you have any examples of values that do not start with 4 and that you know what they translate to? Trying to generalize from a single example can be tricky, as can trying to generalize when all examples have identical portions.

Comment: Are you sure the value decodes as you say? Can you give another example, say from last year?

Comment: The VB code that parses this string is hard coded for the first digit to be '4' and has been since at least 2012.  I'm 95% sure that the 4 stands for century, but I'd like to know for sure so I don't have to do this all again in 2020.

Answer (score 2):

4should stand for weeks since start of year
format for that would be
(weeks since 1st jan, 2last digits of year, days since 1st jan, hours, minutes)

```
WW IY DDD HH MI
```

Comment: Sounds plausible enough to me, could do with more samples to validate

Comment: Umm. We are only in the 3rd week of the year. Unless I'm looking at the wrong calendar.

Comment: in iso format there is 3rd week,  `(IW)`
in non-iso format, we are at 4th `(WW)`
But we really need some more samples. we are still working wiith guess.